# Add pronunciation to text to speech

Tags: text-to-speech

Is there any way to add a pronunciation to OSX text to speech service? I've google for the last few hours without a solution.

Comment: Are you selecting text and running the contextual menu Start Speaking command? You could create an Automator service that replaces text within a selection before passing it on to be spoken. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/204299/french-narrator/204301#204301 for a service that speaks.

Comment: I'm currently doing it with automator, just wondering if there's a more natural way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can affect macOS's text to speech pronunciation. Everything you need to know is in Apple's [Speech Synthesis in OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SpeechSynthesisProgrammingGuide/SpeechOverview/SpeechOverview.html).

Try these two commands in Terminal.app:

```
say "cat"
```

Now to have the individual letters spelt out:

```
say "[[char LTRL]] cat [[char NORM]]"
```

See [Use Embedded Speech Commands to Fine-Tune Spoken Output](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SpeechSynthesisProgrammingGuide/FineTuning/FineTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004365-CH5-SW10) for a long list of modifiers.

If you need to speak in another language, be sure to [use an appropriate voice](http://theworklife.com/graham-miln/2015/09/04/speaking-with-a-french-accent-os-x-say/).

Comment: How do you go about adding it permanently to the text to speech dictionary? Like if I do `say "cat"` again it doesn't spell it out again.

Comment: Please could you [ask this as a separate question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Feel free to link back to this question to provide additional context.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't properly ask what I wanted, I'll modify the question.

Comment: A separate question would be better. The answer here is useful and may help others. A new question can then directly address the other aspect, how to permanently store these changes.

Comment: Alright, I posted my other question

Comment: As of 2024, these no longer work properly but the documentation for them is still on line.